# how to give different solution when the imported data is not same as original?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

i'm new to hadoop. this was the scenario asked by the senior person to check how good i can manage hadoop.

scenario:
You need to give support to the client who is importing data to hdfs from any source. You don't have computer or about files he is extracting, only you need to support through phone.
suppose, he is importing 700 files but the hdfs contains only 550 files in it after importing. where does the remaining files gone wrong?
how do you manage to give different solution asking him to check and extract correct amount of data in hdfs? the client doesn't know anything meaning he is not developer. so if you are giving any solution, you need to give briefly.

he might use any of the components from the sqoop, MR, hive, pig, hbase. please briefly give solution from the components.
Also, it might not be from the components, it could be configuration settings.

You need to provide different possibility asking him to check or provide exact solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. What command did client use to extract the data?
2. What command did client use to check the amount of files on HDFS?
3. Use HDFS WebUI `http://<namenode>:50070` to check the health of namenodes and datanodes
4. Use HDFS WebUI to check whether the files are really missing. From there he can easily browse the FS and see the files contents, he can also count amount of files by copying the folder contents to the notepad
5. If the customer has used `hdfs dfs -put` command the he should have a log of data uploading (it dumps the errors to stdout, so he should see the Java stack traces in his console). Ask whether he see any problems
6. In the same WebUI you have a link to namenode logs. Ask the customer to open the file `hadoop-hdfs-namenode-*.log`, copy to the notepad, scroll to the end and search for ERROR (case sensitive) upside down, giving you information about the errors he see there

In fact, the overall logic really depends on the first two answers, because "loading files" into HDFS might be accomplished in many ways, and the logic of further conversation really depends on what the customer did use